# is it possible now to read smart cards with html5 or hybrid apps in android phones?

Tags: javascript, android, html, nfc

I am a student of Computer Science. I am working on my final year project "**Money Transaction with Smart ID Card**".

My sir, told me to make an android application with java to read Smart ID cards as NFC. But I am thinking to make this with HTML5. I searched a lot but could not find a proper solution. Some stackoverflow questions answered as this API is not yet made, but those questions are older than a year. Isn't is still possible in 2016. I got a link of W3C but could not understand that if it is still possible.

Please check the [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-nfc-20140114/) and help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you take a look at this mail in the archive, than it says that:

> The Near Field Communications Working Group [1] is now closed.
>
> The group has been working on the NFC API specification between
>   October   2012 and November 2014, and the charter [2] period for the
>   group has   expired. During the charter period, the group published
>   the NFC API First   Public Working Draft [3] on 14 January 2014.
>
> After the charter expiration, we have been considering how to continue
>   the   group's work to bring the NFC API specification to the stage of 
>   Recommendation. However, we could not get enough support from browser 
>   vendors for the specification and its implementations due to several
>   issues. The Director has now made a decision to close the Working
>   Group.
>
> We would like to thank the Working Group Chair, Jacques Bourhis
>   (Intel)   and all the participants in the group for their efforts.

Source:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-nfc/2015Apr/0005.html

So I would say that: no. Don't waste your time on this.

There is a community group for this API. You might want to contact the members of that group for more information.
https://www.w3.org/community/web-nfc/

Comment: @MursedulIslamSumon You're welcome. Good luck for the project!